# I am trying to get a list of pages i admin on facebook using the graphapi

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am following the example 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2

I have this working and I can get the user..

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(FB_APP_ID,FB_APP_SECRET);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://localhost:8088' );
$session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] );

if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  $user = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
```

Now i need to do a fql and i am unsure how to the $facebook object??

```
$fql = 'SELECT name,page_id FROM page WHERE page_id IN
 (SELECT page_id FROM    page_admin WHERE uid='.$user->getID() .')';

$ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
                        'method' => 'fql.query',
                        'query' => $fql,
                        ));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use FQL. It been deprecated and will stop working. Use the Graph API instead and do `/me/accounts` as explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/accounts